# Throwing Exception in an EventSubscriber prevent ApiPlatform from serializing it so i only get standard symfony error page

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

i'm trying to do some process in an EventSubscriber listening to the request. To make it simple i want to check a header and refuse the request if i don't find it. It's almost like a Guard, but quite simpler.
In that step i might throw an Exception. And it works, except that i would like apiPlatform to manage the response and serialize it.

I have already configure ApiPlatform with packages/api_platform.yaml

```
api_platform:
    exception_to_status:
        Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException: 403
```

My EventSubscriber is configured like this in services.yaml

```
services:
  app.security.api_subscriber:
    class: App\Security\ApiAccessSubscriber
    arguments:
      - "%api.authorized.keys%"
    calls:
      - [setClient, ["@common-sentry-api"]]
      - [setClientPerUser, ["@common-sentry-peruser"]]
```

My Subscriber describe itself like this:

```
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::REQUEST => ['onKernelRequest', EventPriorities::POST_WRITE],
        ];
    }
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You don't need the api platform `exception_to_status` mapping for that Symfony exception, api platform will know to handle it correctly. And you also missed the piece of code that actually throws the exception.

Comment: @RaresSerban thx for help. I added the exception_to_status part coz it was not managed finely. And which part did i missed ? you speak about my code that should throw the exception ?